# Tabular input Yii2 (Combining Update, Create and Delete on one page)

Tags: php, input, yii2, tabular

There is no solution in the Yii2 guide about [combining update, create and delete of tabular input request](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-tabular-input.html).

I have an issue with updating data of students academic performance using Yii2.For example, I have tabular form like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAQvw.jpg)

The number of columns and rows can be various (e.g. 300 columns of dates). Thus, there will be 3 operations (create, update, delete) for updating academic records of students. It turns out, if I need to render cells with input tags (`<?= $form->field($model, '[$index]value') ?>`) in the View, I will have to create a lot of model objects (rows from the database with the student's progress).

I can't understand how to organize this process correctly. Please help.

Comment: you can try this gii  https://github.com/mootensai/yii2-enhanced-gii

Answer (score 0):

Try out [this](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform) Yii2 extension, it's really easy to use and to set up for dynamic tabular forms.

Comment: Thank you. I solved my problem with the help of AJAX. In general, there is too much to write to handle these 3 operations. And for the end user it is more convenient, I think.